# jQuery - trigger("click") not working after e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to perform async operation right before browser redirects user to `http://example.com` on click.

So, after the ajax call I'm clicking currentTarget again to redirect but it doesn't work.

```html
<a class="notic_click" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
<a class="notic_click" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
```

```js
$(".notic_click").on("click", function(e, options) {
       options = options || {};
      
       // if it hasn't been clicked already
       // run this
       if( !options.hasClicked ) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const self = this;
          
            // some other code

            $.get("http://example.com/hello")
                 .always(function() {
                     $(self).trigger("click", {hasClicked: true});
               });
        } else {
            // I got here, that means e.preventDefault didn't get called and it should redirect
            console.log("should redirect but not redirecting");
        }
 });
```

I tried `$(self).off()` right before the trigger, but to no avail.

I have already tried this:

```
window.location.assign(e.target.href);
```

and this works. But I'm curious as to what is causing the above not to work.

Browser: Mozilla Firefox (78.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine in [isolation](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/z47gwdp0/). That being said, a better approach would be to always call `preventDefault()` to stop the page redirection and then make your async AJAX request. When that request completes you can then use `window.location.assign()` to redirect the user.

```js
$(".notic_click").on("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // I'd suggest putting a loading spinner in the UI here to make it clear
  // to the user that their request is in process.

  $.get("http://example.com/hello").always(() => {
    window.location.assign(e.target.href);
  });
});
```

Comment: I already tried this and it works. However, I'm trying to understand what's wrong with the code in the question.

Comment: The code in your question appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/z47gwdp0/. Can you check the console for any errors.

Comment: is it able to redirect inside the fiddle where Button Button preview is?? because in my case it's not working

Comment: Sure: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/z47gwdp0/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
$(".notic_click").on("click", function(e) {

  if( e.isTrusted) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const self = this;

    // some other code

    $.get("http://example.com/hello")
      .always(function() {
        $(self).click();
      });
  } else {
    // I got here, that means e.preventDefault didn't get called and it should redirect
    console.log("should redirect but not redirecting");
  }
});
```

You can read more about is trusted here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this code piece. You seem to have a logic problem in your code. Since you prevent the default, you should "return" to the default behaviour:

```
<a class="notic_click" href="http://example.com">Button</a>
<a class="notic_click" href="http://example.com">Button</a>


    <script>
        $(".notic_click").on("click", async function (e, options) {
            options = options || {};

            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('do task here');
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            console.log('timeout end');
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

            window.location = this.href;
        });
    </script>
```